# What's the meaning of "as close as anyone gets to seeing wind"?

Tags: meaning

> as close as anyone gets to seeing wind.

I know the meaning of *get to do*. It means " to have the opportunity to do something" Ex: We got to meet all the stars after the show.[1](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get-to-do-something)

But I cannot get the point.

So, could you please explain it to me?

The full text:

> The hill is paved with wild wheat. If the conifers and sagebrush are
>   soloists, the wheat field is a corps de ballet, each stem following
>   all the rest in bursts of movement, a million ballerinas bending, one
>   after the other, as great gales dent their golden heads. The shape of
>   that dent lasts only a moment, and is **as close as anyone gets to
>   seeing wind.**

Answer (score 2):

We cannot actually see the wind, it is invisible, but we are able to see the way that the wind affects the wheat in the wheat field. The author is suggesting that, by looking at the way the wheat stems are bent by the wind, sometimes slightly when the wind is gentle, sometimes significantly when the wind is strong, we are able to form a picture in our minds of the how the air is moving over the wheat field. And this is as close to being able to 'see the wind' as we can get.

Comment: Yes, in this case the (mainly American) phrasal verb 'get to' is not being used.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: *as close as anyone gets to getting to see the wind*  :-)

Comment: Well, if you must.